# Future in Manual Testing?

Tags: automated-testing, manual-testing

How future is in only manual testing. I was and I am weak in programming so I selected software testing and working as software tester since last 4 years. Doing excellent testing. But I heard that after some experience in manual testing it is necessary to learn automation tool , is that fact?

Comment: Hi Helping Hands, welcome to SQA! This is not really a question that is a good fit for the format here, although interesting - because it doesn't really have an answer, just a lot of opinions. It's honestly a question that the whole industry has been discussing for years without any real conclusion - so I'm going to put this on hold.

Comment: @testerab - Okay.no issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to community!
I believe that manual testing should be always important "till the end of the world". But I also deeply believe that software tester should be familiar with some programming language and script language. But, again, if you are really great manual software tester you will be always valuable employee. Good luck.